# Функция gethostbyname() возвращает U\371\346\247 вместо ip

Tags: url, ip, c++

Пытаюсь получить IP адрес сервера по его URL на С++.
Выполняю функцию `gethostbyname("sitename")`. В поле структуры, которую она вернула я выбираю первй адрес: `h_addr_list[0]`. Он мне возвращает что-то такое: `U\371\346\247`.
Это же не IP адрес, помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это IP адрес. Только в бинарном виде. 4 байта. unsigned int в сетевом порядке байт.

Вы структуру-то (`struct hostent` [например здесь](http://www.opennet.ru/cgi-bin/opennet/man.cgi?topic=gethostbyname)), возвращаемую gethostbyname() в файле `<netdb.h>` внимательно посмотрите.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно так что ли ;)

```
const char* GetHostAddress(const char* host_name)
{
    HOSTENT* remoteHost = gethostbyname(host_name);
    if (remoteHost)
    {
        IN_ADDR addr;
        ((unsigned long *)&addr)[0]=
            ((unsigned long **)remoteHost->h_addr_list)[0][0];
        return inet_ntoa(addr);
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    WORD wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    WSADATA w = {0};
    int error = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &w);
    if (error == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    const char* ip_address = GetHostAddress("google.ru");
    if (ip_address != NULL)
    {
        MessageBoxA(0, ip_address, 0,0);
    }

    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

p.s. функция набросанная из ничего, нужно ее проверить и переписать!

Comment: Следует заметить, что `inet_ntoa()` имеет прототип

    char *inet_ntoa(struct in_addr in);

и возвращает **адрес в статическом буфере**. `IN_ADDR` это характерный для Windows (но не \*nix!!!) `typedef`.

Обычно адрес выбирается для дальнейшего использования в `bind()` или `connect()`, которые требуют заполненную структуру `struct sockaddr`.  Часто пишут так (только с проверками)

    struct sockadd_in sin;
    struct hostent *h = gethostbyname(host);
    memcpy((char *)&sin.sin_addr.s_addr,h->h_addr,h->h_length);
    ...
    connect (s,(sock_addr *)&sin, sizeof(sin));

И см. manpages.